# Meteor app fails to read App variable in mobile_config.js

Tags: meteor

I have a Meteor app that fails to read App variable in mobile_config.js  The app runs in browser but Icons and splash do not load and routes do not work properly in Android simulator. No compile errors in console just this when app finally loads in emulator I get:

> (android:http://meteor.local/mobile_config.js:4) Uncaught
>   ReferenceError: App is not defined

I'm starting simulator with meteor run android --port http://my.ip:3000 (using my actual IP address)

I've tried with and without App.accessRule. I have test app that uses same mobile_config.js and it works fine.

I can't include the whole app and not sure what snippet is broken anyway. How can I find out what exactly is failing? There are no other errors logged in terminal. I suspect something other than mobile_config is issue.

Lasest version of following packages installed: 
meteor-platform
underscore
zendy:velociratchet
iron:router
jackyqiu:meteor-jquery-nicescroll
accounts-password
mrt:moment
anti:fake
service-configuration
accounts-ui

Answer (score 1):

You've named your file incorrectly.

Use `mobile-config.js` instead of `mobile_config.js`

Meteor accounts this file slightly differently. It does not run and include code with your app like other javascript files in your project.

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer. The file is now recognized and working properly. It seems it is usually the details like "-" vs. "_" that really matter. Now I can work on rest of the issues ;)